# Como desativa uma tecla em um Form completo?

Tags: .net, winforms, vb.net

Como posso desabilitar tecla <kbd>TAB</kbd> ou <kbd>ALT</kbd> do programa? Exemplo: ao clicar TAB não efetuar nenhuma alteração.

É possível no `KeyDown`?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

No `KeyDown` coloque algo assim:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab || e.Alt) e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/DisableKey.cs).

Obviamente pode colocar as teclas que quiser. Note a diferença entre uma tecla "normal" e uma modificadora. O [`SuppressKeyPress`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_KeyEventArgs_SuppressKeyPress) é o segredo para engolir a tecla sem fazer nada.

Comment: Correto, porém ele funciona normalmente as teclas TAB e ALT. isso que acho estranho.

Comment: É assim, mas como você não colocou seu código não dá para ajudar mais que isto. Tente *debugar* e ver se está entrando aí, executando direito.

Comment: estou utilizando comando SendKeys, para selecionar uma imagem, porém ele está dando TAB no programa junto com Janela de File, então queria bloquear as teclas. assim iria funcionar somente a janela de arquivos.